# Calculation of weighted average using distance matrix only

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, coordinates

Assume that we have a N by N pairwise distance matrix (`D_ij`) of N samples. But we don't have coordinates for these N samples. Also there exists a weight for each sample. I want to calculate the weighted average between set of these points. For example between `s1={1,2,3}` and `s2={4,5,6}`.

It is easy to do that if we had coordinates (x1,x2,...):

```
D{s1,s2} = distance(w1*x1+w2*x2+w3*x3, w4*x4+w5*x5+w6*x6)
```

Is it possible to get the same result without coordinates using pairwise distances and weights only?

I could come up a formula that is defined for the distance between a single sample and a set as follows, but I don't know how to extend it for distance between two sets:
Assuming `s={x1, x2}`

```
D{x3,s} = (w1*D{x1,x3}^2+w2*D{x2,x3}^2)/(w1+w2)-(w1*w2*D{x1,x2}^2)/(w1+w2)^2
```

PS: I know that we can convert the distance matrix to coordinates (i.g. using [multidimensional scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling)). I am looking for a way to skip this step.

Comment: I doubt that there is a unique solution. You can rotate and translate the points arbitrarily and the distances won't change. However, the average will.

Comment: Thanks Nico. I think you have a point. But if that's true, why we can uniquely calculate the distance between a point and a set without coordinates? similar to the formula that I mentioned.

Comment: More thoughts: I was wrong. I think the rotation and translation wont change the result. Please note that we don't want the weighted average coordinates. We want the distance between weighted average of two sets.

Comment: So you want to find the distance of the two sets' averages? Where is the formula from? Maybe its proof contains some more hints on how to extend it. Btw, does the formula assume weights to sum up to 1?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I want to calculate the distance between weighted average of two sets using pairwise distance matrix of samples.  My final goal is to implement a new version of [centroid linkage clustering algorithm](http://www.mathworks.nl/help/stats/linkage.html). I want to assign some weights to the nodes. So instead of calculating the centroid for each cluster, it should calculate the center of mass (weighted average) in each step. It can be done using the coordinate of samples (similar to what I have shown in the question). But not with distance matrix (as far as I know of course)

Answer (score 0):

There is no general way to directly compute the center of mass using nothing but distances. You might try using [Multidimensional Scaling](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multidimensional_scaling) (MDS) to generate (possibly approximate) coordinates for the points in a N-dimensional space. Use these coordinates to calculate the center of mass directly.

N.b. that the coordinates produced by MDS are NOT unique. Any rotation/reflection gives an equally valid solution; this is by design. There may be other geometric symmetries, depending on your data.